# how to edit a table row in a form on the same page using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a standard table with a bunch of rows. I have an edit link on each row. At the top of the page, I have a form that creates new rows. what I want to be able to do is click edit on any row and the data loads into the form at the top for editing...here's the code I have so far:

the index with the form + table:

```
.page-header.position-relative
  %h1
    Expenses
= link_to "Create Expense", "#", :role => "button", :class => "btn btn-small btn-primary", :'data-placement' => 'bottom', :'data-content' => "Before you can create an expense, please create a client.", :'title' => "Getting Started", "data-toggle" => "modal", :id => "create-expense"
.row-fluid{:style => "margin-top:20px; display:none;", :id => "expense-form"}
  .alert.alert-success
    = render "expense_form"
- if current_user.has_expense?
  = render "expense_table"
```

and the partials (form + table):

```
= form_for(@expense, :html => { :style => "margin-bottom:0px !important;" }) do |f|
  - if @expense.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@expense.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this expense from being saved:
      %ul
        - @expense.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  .form-inline
    .input-append.date
      %span.add-on
        %i.icon-calendar
      = f.text_field :date, :class => "input-small", :id => "date-picker", :required => "true", :value => simple_date_if_exists(@expense.date), :placeholder => "Expense Date"
    .input-prepend
      %span.add-on $
      = f.text_field :amount, :class => "input-small", :required => "true", :placeholder => "Amount"
    = f.text_field :category, :class => "input-small", :placeholder => "Category"
    = f.select :client_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@possible_clients, "id", "name"), {:prompt => "Choose Client"}, :class => "span2"
    = f.text_field :note, :placeholder => "Notes", :class => "input"
  .row-fluid{:style => "margin-top:20px;"}
    %label.span5
      = f.file_field :receipt, :style => "display: none;", :class => "ace-file-input", :id => "id-input-file-1"
    .pull-right
      = f.submit "Add Expense", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-small"
      = link_to "Cancel", "#", :style => "color: #333; text-decoration: none;", :class => "btn btn-small", :id => "cancel-expense"
```

and the table:

```
%table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover{:style => "margin-top:20px;"}
  %tr
    %th Date
    %th Amount
    %th Category
    %th Client
    %th Notes
    %th Receipt
    %th
  - @expenses.each do |expense|
    %tr
      %td= expense.date
      %td= number_to_currency(expense.amount)
      %td= expense.category
      %td= expense.client.try(:name)
      %td= truncate(expense.note, :length => 50)
      %td= link_to expense.receipt_file_name, expense.receipt.url, :target => "_blank" unless expense.receipt.blank?
      %td.nolink= link_to "Edit", edit_expense_path(expense)
```

how would i go about doin that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

html sample:

```
<form>
    <input name="col_1" type="textfield"/>
    <input name="col_2" type="textfield"/>
</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td>Item 4</td>
        <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js sample:

```
$("a").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var cols = $(this).closest("tr");
    $("input[name='col_1']").val(cols.find("td:eq(0)").text());
    $("input[name='col_2']").val(cols.find("td:eq(1)").text());
});
```

Then you can use class or other property to filter your link and/your table.

Here the jsfidle: http://jsfiddle.net/WgwKZ/

Fonts:
http://api.jquery.com/